# Outputting data from 5gb file with awk

Tags: csv, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I have a csv file with approximately 300 columns.

I'm using **awk** to create a subset of this file where the 24th column is "CA".

Example of data:

[image]

Here's what I am trying:

```
awk -F "," '{if($24~/CA/)print}' myfile.csv > subset.csv
```

After approximately 10 minutes the subset file grew to 400 mb, and then I killed it because this is too slow.

**How can I speed this up?** Perhaps a combination of sed / awk?

\

Comment: try `awk -F, '$24=="CA"' myfile.csv`

Comment: @AvinashRaj same same

Comment: this is really unbelievable. this is i7 quad core with 24 gigs of RAM, running a fresh install of ubuntu. why should it take this long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:

- `awk` implementations can significantly differ in performance.
- In this particular case, see if using `gawk` (GNU awk) helps.

Ubuntu comes with `mawk` as the default `awk`, which is usually considered faster than `gawk`. However, in the case at hand it seems that `gawk` is significantly faster (related to line length?), at least based on the following simplified tests, which I ran
in a VM on Ubuntu 14.04 on a 1-GB file with 300 columns of length 2.

The tests also include an equivalent `sed` and `grep` command.

Hopefully they provide at least a sense of comparative performance.

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pass in test file
f=$1

# Suppress stdout
exec 1>/dev/null

awkProg='$24=="CA"'

echo $'\n\n\t'" $(mawk -W version 2>&1 | head -1)" >&2
time mawk -F, "$awkProg"  "$f"

echo $'\n\n\t'" $(gawk --version  2>&1 | head -1)" >&2
time gawk -F, "$awkProg"  "$f"

sedProg='/^([^,]+,){23}CA,/p'

echo $'\n\n\t'" $(sed --version  2>&1  | head -1)" >&2
time  sed -En "$sedProg"  "$f"

grepProg='^([^,]+,){23}CA,'

echo $'\n\n\t'" $(grep --version  2>&1 | head -1)" >&2
time grep -E "$grepProg"  "$f"
```

Results:

```
     mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

real    0m11.341s
user    0m4.780s
sys 0m6.464s


     GNU Awk 4.0.1

real    0m3.560s
user    0m0.788s
sys 0m2.716s


     sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

real    0m9.579s
user    0m4.016s
sys 0m5.504s


     grep (GNU grep) 2.16

real    0m50.009s
user    0m42.040s
sys 0m7.896s
```